# Regex or something similar to check if DNS should be blocked or not

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex (or something like it) to use with preg_match that allows me to validate DNS. I will have rules which DNS will be blocked (cannot be used).

For example:

```
google.* (sting google.com cannot work, but sgoogle.com will work)
.google. (any subdomain for google on any TLD would be blocked) etc...
```

So I will have variable $rules with rules like above:

```
$rules = array('google.*', '.google.');
```

And I want to check if $dns = "sgoogle.com" should be blocked or not.

How to do this?

Comment: What's the intended function of the program? Eg. What is the input to the program, and what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
<?php
    $testurls = array(
        'www.google.com',
        'www1.google.co.jp',
        '.google.com',
        'www.sgoogle.com',
        'www.example.com',
        'www.example.xxx',
        'www.specialdummy.org',
    );
    $rules = array(
        '.google.*', 
        '*.xxx',
        '.*dummy.',
        // more ...
    );
    $regex = '';
    foreach($rules as $rule) {
        $regex .= (!empty($regex) ? '|' : '') . 
            str_replace(array('.','*'), array('\.','.*?'), $rule);
    }
    echo "Regex: $regex<br />";
    foreach($testurls as $url) {
        $notallowed = preg_match('/('.$regex.')/', $url);
        echo $url . ': ' . ($notallowed ? 'NOT allowed' : 'allowed') . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
www.google.com       NOT allowed
www1.google.co.jp    NOT allowed
.google.com          NOT allowed
www.sgoogle.com      allowed
www.example.com      allowed
www.example.xxx      NOT allowed
www.specialdummy.org NOT allowed
```

Rule Notes:

- The rules are taken as parts of a regular expression.
- The rules may contain periods (.) and asterisks (*).
- **Periods are taken literally**.
- **Asterisks mean "any string of characters until the next character is found or until the end of the rule"**.
- Other regex control characters may be escaped by a backslash (\)

Comment: I update the code with a set of test url. Please see the "Rule notes". You might have to modifiy these vs. your assumption.